# How to run a macro after a rule on outlook is executed?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have set a rule on outlook to delete permanently incoming email (based on subject condition).
I also set a vba macro to forward incoming emails (because any rules to forward emails are disabled by IT).

**The problem:**

the macro of (forward incoming emails) is auto run before the outlook rule is executed.
I need to run my macro after that rule on outlook is executed and finished.
I do not prefer to transfer the rule itself into a vba code.
In advance, all thanks for your support.

```
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)             'Forward Incoming emails
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem
 
    If Not TypeOf item Is MailItem Then Exit Sub
 
     Set objMail = item
     Set objForward = objMail.Forward
 
        With objForward
            .Recipients.Add ("***@yahoo.com")
            .Recipients.ResolveAll
            .Send
        End With
 
         Set objMail = Nothing
         Set objForward = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force the rule to run on startup.

The assumption is this will run before ItemAdd code.

In ThisOutlookSession

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim st As Store
Dim myRules As Rules
Dim rl As Rule
Dim ruleName As String

Dim k As Long

' get store (can be any store)
Set st = Session.defaultStore
Debug.Print st.DisplayName

' get rules from specified store
Set myRules = st.GetRules()

ruleName = "name of rule to delete incoming email based on subject"

For k = 1 To myRules.count

    Set rl = myRules(k)
    Debug.Print myRules(k).name
    
    If myRules(k).name = ruleName Then
        ' Regardless of rule store,
        '  the applicable Folder is by default the inbox of the default store
        ' Designate a folder if not the default inbox
        rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
        Debug.Print ruleName & " has run."
        Exit For
    End If

Next

End Sub
```